# Which sequences arise as the eventuality filter of a sequence?

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $X$ denote a topological space. Can we characterize  the filters on $X$ that arise as the eventuality filter of a sequence?

Comment: Any filter with a countable set inside... no?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that such an eventuality filter of a sequence must contain a countable set $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Look at the set of all countable subsets of $A$. These have empty intersection or some countable or finite intersection. Try to think of a sequence that has tails that behave like that.